# Rails console: Update attributes and save to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to update existing records in the rails console.

```
Order.all.each do |tname| tname.team = User.where(:id => tname.user_id).pluck(:team).shift end
```

Is working but the result is not getting saved to the DB.

Both

```
Order.all.each do |tname| tname.team = User.where(:id => tname.user_id).pluck(:team).shift self.update_columns(team: tname.team) end
```

Or

```
Order.all.each do |tname| tname.team = User.where(:id => tname.user_id).pluck(:team).shift self.update_attributes(team: tname.team) end
```

Are not working. (NoMethodError: undefined method `update_attributes' for main:Object)

Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Edit (schema):

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.text     "team"
end

create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer  "user_id"
 t.string   "team"
end
```

Comment: Which db you are using? @Harakiri

Comment: I`m using Postgres

Comment: instead of `self.update_attributes(team: tname.team)` just use `tname.save`. try like this @Harakiri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange fix:

By typing it in 2 steps that works:

1) `Order.all.each do |tname| tname.team = User.where(:id => tname.user_id).pluck(:team).shift`

2) `tname.save end`

Instead of

`Order.all.each do |tname| tname.team = User.where(:id => tname.user_id).pluck(:team).shift tname.save end`.

Absolutely no clue why..

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is highly inefficient:

```
Order.all.each do |tname|
  tname.team = User.where(:id => tname.user_id).pluck(:team).shift
end
```

You hit the database with every order, resulting in many queries. Also, selecting the team via pluck is... wierd. If you want to get a `User` and access its team use:

```
User.find_by(id: tname.user_id).team
```

But you should do this in one query anyway. If you set up the relations correctly, this should do the job:

```
Order.joins(:user).update_all('team = users.team')
```

Comment: what is `tname.team` supposed to do then, if you don't have that column? Add your schema please

Comment: I've recently added `team` to Orders. Every new record is populated correctly but I want to have the past Orders also populated with the respective teamname of the user.

Comment: I've added the schema. @TheChamp

Comment: did you set up the relations with `has many` and `belong to`?

Comment: Ok now try it: I used `.update_all('orders.team = users.team')` instead of `.update_all('team = users.team')`

Comment: "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "users""